# Django set_password() method in UserManager is saving plain text

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm trying to make an endpoint for registration.
When I create a new user, a plain text would be saved in the password field. But, when I add a user through admin, it would be hashed. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

model.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        **extra_fields,
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import User
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['email'],
            validated_data['password']
        )
        return user
```

view.py

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.save()
    return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `RegisterSerializer.create` method:

```
def create(self, data):
    user = User.objects.create(**data)
    return user
```

You're taking the `password` from user as text, and calling `User.objects.create` to create the `User` instance. The `create` method of `UserManager` (which eventually is delegated to the `QuerySet`) is generic meaning the `password` field will be populated as the input data as-is, without any *hashing-salting-peppering*.

As it is saved as plaintext, Django can't determine the format it is saved in (the typical format is `hash_algo$iterations$salt$hash`), so it can't find out the hashing algorithm, salt, hash from it; hence the error *invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm*.

`UserManager` exposes the method `create_user` for this exact purpose of creating the user via passing a plain-text password and doing all these operations there, you should leverage that:

```
def create(self, data):
    user = User.objects.create_user(**data)
    #                   ^^^^ Here
    return user
```

Or you can use `set_password` directly on the user instance in the serializer, but as you can use `create_user` easily you should go with that.

Comment: I changed it to create_user() but, it's still giving me the same error. :(

Comment: @user8229795 Create a new user through the API and login with that user. And update all your existing users from database to set proper passwords (using `set_password`).

Comment: I deleted db and migrations and it still didn’t work. Thank you for your time tho.  Is there an easier way to do this? But I do want to add fields in the model and use different authentication.

Comment: @user8229795 Please edit your question and add the full traceback you're getting now.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't have an error when creating but, when I check the DB, it is not hashed.